# Couldn't read complex properties from yaml in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Couldn't read complex properties from yaml in Spring boot application. Here are the different pieces

### yaml file

```
spring:
   profiles: dev
   test: BLAHSSD
   serversList: 
    - host: localhost
      port: 27017
      db: myDB
      username: xxx
      password: yyy
```

### Java Classes

Server.java

```
public class Server {

    String host;

    int port;

    String db;

    String username;

    String password;

    public Server() {

    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getDb() {
        return db;
    }

    public void setDb(String db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Server [host=" + host + ", port=" + port + ", db=" + db + ", username=" + username + ", password="
                + password + "]";
    }

}
```

Configuaration Reader

```
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/tmp/test.yaml")
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class TestDBConfiguration {

    private String test;

    private List<Server> serversList;

    public List<Server> getServersList() {
        return serversList;
    }

    public void setServersList(List<Server> serversList) {
        this.serversList = serversList;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

I am able to read the 'test' attribute when i comment the serversList attributes. But keep getting this exception for serverList:

> Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
>   required type 'java.util.List' for property 'serversList'

Answer (score 1):

I believe your yaml structure is invalid. Try to change it to:

```
spring:
   profiles: dev
   test: BLAHSSD
   serversList: 
    - server:
        host: localhost
        port: 27017
        db: myDB
        username: xxx
        password: yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings):

> #### 24.6.4 YAML shortcomings
>
> YAML files can’t be loaded via the `@PropertySource` annotation. So in
>   the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a
>   properties file.

Furthermore, Java [erases generics information at compile time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So at runtime Spring sees `serverList`'s type as `List`, not `List<Server>`, and it cannot convert your configuration properties to a list of `Server` objects.